# PyQt4 Local Directory view with option to select folders

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I know how to make a simple QTreeView() with a QDirModel (or QFileSystemModel) to show the files/folders in the system but I want to add a checkbox next to each of them so the user can select some of the folders/files on his system. Obviously, I also need to know which ones he has chosen. Any hints?

basically something like this...

[image]

Below is a sample code that makes a directory view but without the checkboxes.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QtGui.QDirModel()
    tree = QtGui.QTreeView()
    tree.setModel(model)

    tree.setAnimated(False)
    tree.setIndentation(20)
    tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

    tree.setWindowTitle("Dir View")
    tree.resize(640, 480)
    tree.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subclass QDirModel, and reimplement `data(index,role)` method, where you should check, if `role`  is `QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole`. If it is, you should return either `QtCore.Qt.Checked` or `QtCore.Qt.Unchecked`. Also, you need to reimplement `setData` method as well, to handle user checks/unchecks, and `flags` to return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable flag, which enables user checking/unchecking. I.e.:

```
class CheckableDirModel(QtGui.QDirModel):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QDirModel.__init__(self, None)
    self.checks = {}

def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role != QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
        return QtGui.QDirModel.data(self, index, role)
    else:
        if index.column() == 0:
            return self.checkState(index)

def flags(self, index):
    return QtGui.QDirModel.flags(self, index) | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable

def checkState(self, index):
    if index in self.checks:
        return self.checks[index]
    else:
        return QtCore.Qt.Unchecked

def setData(self, index, value, role):
    if (role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole and index.column() == 0):
        self.checks[index] = value
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), index, index)
        return True 

    return QtGui.QDirModel.setData(self, index, value, role)
```

Then you use this class instead of `QDirModel`:

```
model = CheckableDirModel()
tree = QtGui.QTreeView()
tree.setModel(model)
```

Comment: This works just fine but do you know how to modify it so when one clicks on C: then all subcategories get clicked and when one clicked a subcategory C: become a dot (half-checked) ?

Comment: @Kiarash You should change children and parent indices of `index` in `setData` accordingly. To obtain a child index, use `QModelIndex.child`. To obtain a parent index, use `QModelIndex.parent`. To obtain a number of children of given index you should use `QDirModel.rowCount`. See [this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmodelindex.html) and [this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowCount)

Comment: So in the setData, I simply added this: for i in range(self.rowCount(index)):              self.setData(index.child(i,0),value,role)  BUT it's so slow if one clicks on C: . Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @Kiarash It's slow, because it has to traverse the whole hierarchy and add it into the list. An alternative approach would be to store not checked indexes, but paths of checked items. Then in `checkState` you can check if the file path is in `self.checks` OR if a prefix of given file path is in `self.checks`.

Comment: are you saying that when one checked a box, the path goes into a dictionary and when we are checking for foo/bar/text.dat we first check if foo is in the dictionary or if foor/bar is or if foo/bar/text.dat ...

Comment: you can check if the index has children by self.hasChildren(index), if true: do a recursiveCheck by for i in xrange(childrenNum): child = self.index(i, 0, index) self.setData(child, value, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)